# Plumbago auriculata without flowers

Tags: plant-care, shrubs, flowering

enter image description hereMy Plumbago auriculata has not bloomed this year. I pruned it, in February like I do every year,  I not modified the watering or fertilization but .... no flowers. What can it be?[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you say where you are in the world and add a photo of the plant to your post please?

Comment: I 'm in Portugal. I d'not have photos but the Plumbago seems to be well, vigorous, without diseases and without bugs.Have I done something wrong with pruning this year, too late, too early, too much ....I like this plant so much because it is so simple to treat in the Mediterranean climate .....

Comment: Did you have a colder than usual March/April? Doesn't sound like you pruned at the wrong time, usual recommendation is January or early Feb.

Comment: yes maybe, a little cooler than usual and more rain

Comment: In that case, it maybe just late... but you should closely inspect the plant for signs of infestation or disease (look under leaves as well as on top). If its healthy, hopefully you might find signs of budding in preparation for flowering. If you cut it back really hard this year, that might account for it   too - it would certainly delay flowering

Comment: Hello Bamboo, I just uploaded photos of the Plumbagos. They are vigorous and very healthy. And just like before, backward. I was able to detect in the lower branches the first flowers. I hope they will soon appear in all of them. In blues and white.

Comment: Nothing much wrong with those then, by the looks of them. They're obviously just late, hope they come into full flower soon.